# How to display the category dropdown auto search list when key press?

Tags: wp-query, categories

I have a search field. There is no issue with the search if I enter anything on this and click on button then it's redirecting on the page where I can get my search result.

What I am doing is, I have to display the category dropdown auto search list when the user enters any text in the search field. I found one plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/) also demo here (https://lite.ajaxsearchpro.com/). I am trying to do the same but I can't use the plugin.

I need to know what query I have to use on the ajax to get the output?

Form code

```
function search_form($atts) { 
     $form = '<section class="universalSearch"><div class="search search-form"><form role="search" method="get" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">SEARCH</label>
     <input type="search" class="search-field universalSearchField" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s"  placeholder="Search" id="searchdata" />
     <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="search-submit" value="'. esc_attr__('Go', 'domain') .'" />
     </form></div></section>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script>

             (function($) {  // ready handler
$(".universalSearchField").keypress(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { action: "universalSearchlist", keyword: $("#searchdata").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#autocategories").html(data);
        }
    });
    });

    })(jQuery);
        </script>';
    
     return $form;
}

add_shortcode( 'get_search_form', 'search_form');
```

AjAX code

```
add_action('wp_ajax_universalSearchlist','universalSearch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_universalSearchlist','universalSearch');
function universalSearch(){
    $data='';
    $args = array(
     's' => $_REQUEST[ 'universalSearchlist' ],
     'cat' => 'category'
);
    
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    foreach ($the_query->posts as $post) {
        var_dump($post);
    }
    

    //endif;
    //die();
    return $data;
    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "category dropdown"? The [plugin demo](https://lite.ajaxsearchpro.com/) doesn't have any category dropdown there, just a search box where you can type a keyword and then the search results (posts with thumbnail, title and excerpt) are loaded via AJAX right onto the current page. Edit: Never mind, I saw it.

Comment: I have to display my category on dropdown instated of the post. I mean I have to display my category list when user enter on search

Comment: That plugin displaying the post i have to display category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to know what query I have to use on the AJAX to get the output?

In the comments, you said, "*I am looking to search only for categories*", so for that, you can simply use [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) (or [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) for custom taxonomies) and set the `search` arg to the submitted search keyword:

```php
// Get the categories assigned to ANY posts that matched the search keyword.
$terms = get_categories( array(
    'search' => sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['universalSearchlist'] ),
) );

// Then display the categories or do whatever is necessary. (I used 'echo' for testing.)
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $cat_link = get_category_link( $term );
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $cat_link ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a><br>';
}

/* Or using get_terms():
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'search'   => sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['universalSearchlist'] ),
    'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
) );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        ... your code.
    }
}
*/
```

So there's no need for `WP_Query` unless if you wanted only the categories assigned to posts that matched the search keyword.

### Additional Notes

1. Actually, I suggest you to use the REST API for [searching the categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#list-categories) — e.g. you'd make your AJAX requests to `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?search=<keyword>`, but you can ask another question for that.
2. In your `universalSearch()` function, you should call `wp_die()` and there's no need to `return` anything (the `wp_ajax_` hooks are *action* hooks, *not* filter hooks).
3. You should really enqueue your scripts (`.js`) using `wp_enqueue_script()` and you should just use the default jQuery script that came bundled with WordPress.
4. Your AJAX JS is not actually sending the search keyword to the server, so in addition to the `action` parameter, you should add `universalSearchlist: $( this ).val()` to the second parameter for `$.post()`.

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer

Comment: I have tried your code, I have 3 categories, Movies, Books and Fruits, and when I enter any letter in the search field then I am getting my above categories but the issue is here, If I enter Mov then also I am getting my all three categories. I have to show only Movies like search function.

Comment: I think I have to use like in query for searching the records

Comment: Actually, are you looking to search for posts or only categories that matched the search keyword (regardless of what posts the categories are assigned to)?

Comment: I am looking to search only for categories.

Comment: Does the revised answer help? (and btw, I've already deleted my answer to your other question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/373601/how-to-display-the-categories-and-custom-categories-using-wp-query))

Comment: Give me sometime to check.

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer, As of now I have three categories which are  Movies, Books and Fruits but when I enter any other text then also I am getting my cateories.

Comment: I am displaying my categories in the autoselect dropdown. I think I have to use if condition if found then display if not then display not found.

Comment: What do you mean by "any other text"? What keyword you tried and what were the results/categories returned? But you should know, if you entered `boo`, then `Bool` and `Boo cat` would both match.

Comment: Yes, If I entered Boo then Bool and Boo cat will match but I am enting the Xee then also I am getting my categories.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112302/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-naren-verma).

Comment: Yes,it's working for me, instated of $_REQUEST['universalSearchlist'] i have to use $_REQUEST['keyword']